# BIRT spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, birt

New to BIRT, started 3 days back.

### Requirement

Will have REPORTING menu in the existing web application, which will give option to choose the type of report(pdf and chart(drilled down also)) 
and generate the selected chart with the mentioned date.

### What I had done so far

Tried stand-alone report application using sample database.

created a birt rest service, but not sure how to feed data to that.

### Calrification required

1. Do I need to create a template using report design eclipse plugin and an application which is a spring boot where I can connect to 
   database using hibernate and feed the template with data or is there any better approach in this?
2. My application consists of REST API and the client will consume it. So what will be the return type of the birt web service? Is it a byte stream?
3. To run BIRT on existing tomcat server, Do I need any other libraries.

Has been referred a lot of articles regarding BIRT, really stuck at integrating with an existing application. Thanks  in advance